# FCM push notification giving "error":"NotRegistered" in php

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have one problem in **FCM Push notification**.in my php project.
in my code i define different different array. when i print my array is giving me proper result so why when i run my file in browser it's giving me this error

```
{"multicast_id":7882239151284835554,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}end
```

please help me, Thanks.

Hear is my code

```
    // Send Push Notification
if($user['device_token'] != '') {
    $server_key = 'AAAA***********91Z9Y69';
    $registrationIds = 'dLDIms************SAss';
    $msg = array('body'  => "Your Wait is Over!",
                 'title' => "New stages unlocked. Let's Play!!",
                 'icon'  => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
                 'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/);
    $fields = array('to' => $registrationIds,
                    'data'  => $msg);
    $headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $server_key,
                     'Content-Type: application/json');
    //print_r($headers); die();
    #Send Reponse To FireBase Server    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close( $ch );
    #Echo Result Of FireBase Server
    echo $result; 
    die('end');
    }
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this and, if so, how?